# EasyPHP 16.1 DevServer Fresh install mysql issue

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I've done a fresh install of 16.1 on two machines and ran into the same issue on both so I'm going to assume its not just me.

Windows 10 - Latest updates and all.

First, I'm getting fatal javascript errors all over phpmyadmin in firefox but thats a whole other issue (maybe).

I set up a global root user that I use to import databases from remote servers. My name rick@'%' by running the following command:

grant all privileges on *.* to rick@'%' identified by 'somepass';

Success. Ok great.

Try to run an import. Fails permissions.

I go and look at the mysql.user table and I see at least one problem the other is just plain weird.

## 1 - All privilege fields are ticked to N and not Y.

## 2 - The weird one, I have my password hash saved in the "plugin" column and not the "authentication_string" column. I'll get to why thats kinda weird to me in a minute.

So anyway I manually edit the user, changing all N to Y and move the password string to to the authentication string field.

flush privileges

Try to import again - it works.

Ok great, now I need to set up the user account for that database so again, I:

grant all privileges on dbname.* to dbuser@localhost identified by 'somepass';

Ok seems to work, I can load the site and browse... that is until I have to restart mysql or reboot my machine or something. Then once that happens I try to run the website and I get hit with this error:

mysql said: Unknown plugin '*HFDGYHUFJEFGHOIFJEFLEJIJCFIRG" bla bla bla

Ok.... I go and look at the user table and low and behold the password string is in the plugin field... but wait a minute, how was this even working at all up until the restart? Thats just confusing as hell.

Anyway, again, I move the password string to the authentication string field and flush privileges and boom it works.

SO I ask simply, why the is the fresh install of mysql on easyphp devserver 16.1 so funged up?

Is anyone else having issues like this?

Is there any way to manually fix this?

One thing I found weird was there is still a password field in the mysql.user table. Is this the problem? I thought they got rid of that column? maybe I'm wrong IDK.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin, MySQL, and PHP versions are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the mysql service was being delivered with the package in a state where it needed to have the "mysql-upgrade" command ran on it. I had to run the command to fix another issue I was having and after I did that user passwords are saved in the proper field. I would post the full command I used but that was a few weeks ago and I dont have it handy right now.